# Printing scrambled with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have a web page and I'm trying to print it. I'm using a bootstrap navbar. The problem is that when I use the bootstarp navbar the printing preview is not making any sense. I see lines of code int the page instead of the actual content.
the problem only happens when I add the refferance to bootstrap.min.css(as seen on the code below)
my page (the relevant part):

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="design.css">
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" >
        <div class="container">

            <a href="http://localhost/sapir/registration.php" class="navbar-brand"><img src="http://sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/41032_147610068590926_4173889_n.jpg" id="logo"></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                    <li><a href="javascript&#058;print(document)"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/128x128/devices/print_printer.png" id="logo" ></a></li>
                    <li><a href="Register.html">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="customer.html">Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Administrator.html">Administrator</a></li>
                    <li><a href="account.html">Accounts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Illustration.html">Illustration</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/sapir/php-calendar-2.0/index.php">שיבוץ</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What do I need to do so the page would print correctly (without the navbar)?

this is an image of the problem: http://postimg.org/image/mk0vwde8b/6e80e14d/

Comment: Is it necessary to display the navbar on print? If not, `display: none` in the print css. Other than that, it sounds like you have an html error. Run your code through: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: this html, I'm only importing it to a php page, I want to print the php content and not the navbar. The solution below isn't working out for me. any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS media-query to create a class that hides when the page is printed.

```
@media print {    
    .print-hide .print-hide * {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Now add the class `.print-hide` to the navbar and anything else you'd like to hide when printing the page!

Comment: The navigation bar is not hiding when you print?

Comment: I can't tell, the printable content is not what seen on the page, It's like it's trying to print the code lines and the url's

Comment: could you provide a screenshot or a direct link? Hard to wrap my head around it.

Comment: this is the image with the problem : http://postimg.org/image/mk0vwde8b/6e80e14d/